# Is there a way to speed up this list comprehension?

Tags: python, pygame

I've implemented "Langtons Loops" using Python/Pygame, and the larger the array of "Cells", the slower my program runs.
Basic profiling shows that this line is taking up the most time:

```
matchSet = [r for r in ruleSet if r[:5] == buff]
```

Code Context:

```
surrBuff = []

surrBuff.append(str(self.dispBuff[y][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y-1][x]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y][x+1]) + str(self.dispBuff[y+1][x]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y][x-1]))
surrBuff.append(str(self.dispBuff[y][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y][x+1]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y+1][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y][x-1]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y-1][x]))
surrBuff.append(str(self.dispBuff[y][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y+1][x]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y][x-1]) + str(self.dispBuff[y-1][x]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y][x+1]))
surrBuff.append(str(self.dispBuff[y][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y][x-1]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y-1][x]) + str(self.dispBuff[y][x+1]) + 
                    str(self.dispBuff[y+1][x]))`

matchSet = []
for buff in surrBuff:
    #matchSet = [r for r in ruleSet if r.startswith(buff)]
    matchSet = [r for r in ruleSet if r[:5] == buff]

    if len(matchSet) > 0:
        break
```

`ruleSet` is an array of rules - 105 in total.
`surrBuff` is the set of surrounding cells of the current cell.

The idea is to find a matching rule in the `ruleSet` given the current cell value and the possible
combinations of surrounding cells.

Max array size is about 40 * 50 cells and I notice slowdown once the display array hits about 20*50 cells.

Is there a better way to find the matching rule given the setup I've described or is this just a limitation of what I'm trying to do here?

Profiling:

```
ncalls          tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

  1    0.000    0.000   47.707   47.707 <string>:1(<module>)
2072040/465    2.531    0.000    5.054    0.011 copy.py:128(deepcopy)
  2046000    0.288    0.000    0.288    0.000 copy.py:182(_deepcopy_atomic)
26040/465    0.928    0.000    5.051    0.011 copy.py:200(_deepcopy_list)
    26040    0.021    0.000    0.030    0.000 copy.py:242(_keep_alive)
        1    0.063    0.063   47.707   47.707 langLoops2.py:100(mainLoop)
   509601    6.273    0.000   37.883    0.000 langLoops2.py:36(calcNewCellValue)
   835660   29.295    0.000   29.295    0.000 langLoops2.py:59(<listcomp>)
      465    0.338    0.001   38.222    0.082 langLoops2.py:85(updateCalcBuff)
      464    0.377    0.001    0.876    0.002 langLoops2.py:93(draw)
'''
```

Comment: what is the data type of `buff`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the algorithm you're implementing, but generally you'll find that numpy will provide zero-copy multi dimensional arrays which will likely be more performant than the built-in lists -- I can't tell from your profile here and the code if the calls to copy are the result of the rules or just your list comprehension output

Comment: yes, `numpy` will *massively* speed up your code.  Likely ~100x+

Comment: If the data type of buff isn't covered by numpy, it might be covered by Cython which will increase somewhere between 5 and 1000x:
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html

Comment: A minor comment on the code. You do not have to do this `if len(matchSet) > 0:` the 'truthyness' of a collection is determined by whether it has anything in it (an empty collection returns `False`). So you can just use `if matchSet:`. If you run pylint on your code it will recommend this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always compare to the first five elements of the rules, it might make sense to create a dictionary from those rules and then look up the matching rules from that dictionary.

```
# create rule dict (just once, not within the loop)
ruleDict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for r in ruleSet:
    ruleDict[r[:5]].append(r)

...

    # get matchSet from dictionary
    matchSet = ruleDict[buff]
```

Also, unrelated to this, there is quite a bit of deepcopying going on in your profile output. It is generally considerably faster to create your own specialized copy logic, e.g. `list(map(list, original))` for a list of lists, than using `deepcopy`.

Comment: Yes I'm using deepcopy because I have 2 buffers. One to display current values and one to calculate the next display values. I copy the calc buffer to display buffer using deepcopy

self.updateCalcBuff()    -----> update next state using current display
self.dispBuff = deepcopy(self.calcBuff) -----------> copy to display for output

Comment: @granth1974 Answering to your comment under the other answer: Yes, that was a typo, it should have been `ruleDict[r[:5]].append(r)`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need the entire list if you only want to know if there is at least one match.

```
    for buff in surrBuff:  
        if any(r[:5] == buff for r in ruleSet):
            break
```

`any` will return as soon as it finds an element you would have added to the list.

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to find and return the matching rule because the format of the rules is "cnnnnx" where c is the current cell, n is the neighbouring cells and x is the new value to set the current cell to

Comment: @granth1974 You could use `next((r for ...), None)` to get just the first matching rule (but using a dict would still be faster)

Comment: @tobias_k - using a dictionary to store the slices looks to have improved the performance. I couldn't use  ruleDict[r:5].append(r) directly as I got a "slice not hashable" error but just used

`for r in ruleSet:
            s = r[:5]
            self.ruleDict[s].append(r)`